# fgetc only reads UTF8 encoded file. not working for UTF16

Tags: c, utf-8, file-handling, utf-16, fgetc

My aim is to find the encoding of a text file by dividing the size of the file by the number of characters in the file. but fgetc only reads UTF8 encoded files. not working for UTF16. Kindly help me to solve this problem or suggest me if any substitute for fgetc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() 
{ 
    findEncode("C:\\UTF-8_TestCase\\TestCase1.txt");
}

int findEncode(char *str){
    int ch = NumberOfCharecter(str);
    int size = SizeOfFile(str);
    if(size/ch == 1){
        printf("UTF-8");
    }else if(size/ch == 2){
        printf("UTF-16");
    }else {
        printf("UTF-32");
    }       
}

int NumberOfCharecter(char *str){
    FILE *fptr; 
    char ch; 
    int character=1; 
    fptr=fopen(str,"r"); 
    if(fptr==NULL) 
     { 
         printf("File does not exist or can not be opened."); 
     } 
 
          while(1)
          {
            ch = fgetc(fptr); //fgetc only reads UTF8 encoded file. not working for UTF16
              if(ch==EOF)
                break;
              character++;     
          } 
          fclose(fptr);
          
        printf("The number of characters in the  file %s are : %d\n\n",str,character-1);         
        return character-1; 
}

//SizeOfFile working well
int SizeOfFile(char *str) {
    FILE *fptr; 
    char ch; 
    int  sz;
    fptr=fopen(str,"r+"); 
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell(fptr);
    printf("the size of the file is %d \n\n", sz);
    fclose(fptr);
    return sz;      
}
```

Comment: How do you know the "number of characters in the file"? And what do you even mean by the word "character"? The Unicode specification carefully avoids that word because it is very ambiguous. How do you distinguish between UTF16-LE and UTF16-BE? If the file starts with a byte order mark (BOM), you should rely on that.

Comment: Perhaps [`fgetwc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetwc) would be better?

Comment: @RolandIllig please tell me a way to find the encode of a file using C

Comment: @TedLyngmo does not work

Comment: "a way to find the encode of a file using C" this does not exist. You can guess based on content, but that will be just that: a guess.

Comment: Did you already search for "c detect file encoding"? There's plenty of information about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     char ch; 
>     …
>             ch = fgetc(fptr); //…
>               if(ch==EOF)
> ```

You wrongly assign the return value of `fgetc()` to a `char`; in order to compare it to `EOF`, you have to define `int ch`. After this, you'll find that `NumberOfCharecter()` returns the same number as `SizeOfFile()`, since the *character* read by `fgetc()` is not a character in the sense of an encoding, it's independent from that.

Comment: kindly tell me a better way to do this task.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: [How to determine if uploaded file is in UTF-8 or UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459741/how-to-determine-if-uploaded-file-is-in-utf-8-or-utf-16)